# Display Read-Protected Image from S3 with Flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2, boto3

I have a flask application that generates a presigned url in order to display private images to users. But for some reason, the image is not showing, only it's alternative text (though I know the client is connected and the URL is being generated for the correct image)

Here's my Flask Code:

```
@app.route("/get_image", methods=['GET','POST'])
    name_cursor = db.query ##finds the name of the users image
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], region_name='us-east-1')
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                            Params={
                                'Bucket': os.environ['S3_BUCKET'],
                                'Key': name_cursor['img'],
                            },                                  
                            ExpiresIn=3600)

    render_template("test.html",url=url)
```

And then inside the template:

```
<div class="avatar">
     <img src="{{ url }}" alt="Thumbnail Image">
</div>
```

Any insights into what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked by changing the region_name?

Comment: Yes, but it did not fix it. The bucket is located in that region.